# Laravel migration table field's type change

Tags: php, laravel, migration

Following is my file *2015_09_14_051851_create_orders_table.php*.
And I want to change `$table->integer('category_id');` as a string with new migration.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateOrdersTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('orders', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('num');
            $table->integer('user_id');

            $table->text('store_name');
            $table->integer('store_name_publication');

            $table->string('postal_code', 255);
            $table->string('phone_number', 255);

            $table->text('title');
            $table->text('description');

            $table->string('list_image_filename1', 255);
            $table->string('list_image_filename2', 255)->nullable();
            $table->string('list_image_filename3', 255)->nullable();
            $table->string('list_image_filename4', 255)->nullable();
            $table->string('list_image_filename5', 255)->nullable();

            $table->integer('term');

            $table->datetime('state0_at')->nullable();
            $table->datetime('state1_at')->nullable();
            $table->datetime('state2_at')->nullable();
            $table->datetime('state3_at')->nullable();
            $table->datetime('state4_at')->nullable();
            $table->datetime('state5_at')->nullable();
            $table->datetime('state6_at')->nullable();
            $table->datetime('state7_at')->nullable();
            $table->datetime('state8_at')->nullable();
            $table->datetime('state9_at')->nullable();
            $table->datetime('state10_at')->nullable();

            $table->integer('category_id');
            $table->integer('target_customer_sex');
            $table->integer('target_customer_age');

            $table->integer('payment_order');
            $table->integer('num_comment');
            $table->integer('num_view');
            $table->string('num_pop');

            $table->integer('money');
            $table->integer('point');

            $table->datetime('closed_at');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('orders');
    }

}
```

Comment: `$table->string('category_id');`

Comment: no I want to change only that type using other migration file

2015_10_05_021049_change_category_id_to_orders_table

Answer (score 121):

update: 31 Oct 2023, Still usable on laravel 10.x https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/migrations#modifying-columns

To make some change to existing db, you can modify column type by using  `change()` in migration.

This is what you could do

```
Schema::table('orders', function ($table) {
    $table->string('category_id')->change();
});
```

please note you need to add **doctrine/dbal** dependency to composer.json

```
composer require doctrine/dbal
```

For more information you can find it here https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/migrations#modifying-columns

Comment: Now I'm using laravel 4.2

Comment: Still usable in Laravel 5.5 for anyone wondering. (as this answer is already a few years old)

Comment: Yes. You can check it out from here [Modifying Column](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations#modifying-columns) ( Laravel 5.5)

Comment: How can I change string to int and add default value? I tried this but PostgreSQL throws cast error.
`$table->integer('score')->default(0)->change();`

Answer (score 48):

The [standard solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32940664/2615737) didn't work for me, when changing the type from *TEXT* to *LONGTEXT*.

I had to it like this:

```
public function up()
{
    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE mytable MODIFY mycolumn  LONGTEXT;');
}

public function down()
{
    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE mytable MODIFY mycolumn TEXT;');
}
```

This could be a Doctrine issue. More information [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/9636).

Another way to do it is to use the string() method, and set the value to the text type max length:

```
    Schema::table('mytable', function ($table) {
        // Will set the type to LONGTEXT.
        $table->string('mycolumn', 4294967295)->change();
    });
```

Comment: This is specially useful for DECIMAL columns.

Comment: I can confirm this behavior. In order to change a column from text to mediumtext I had to do this:

$table->string('messages', 16777215)->nullable()->change();

Comment: `$table->longText('mycolumn')->change();`

Comment: This is a good solution, since Laravel Migrations don't support changing any other field type when there's another ENUM field on the same table.

Comment: But it cant run the test

Answer (score 12):

2018 Solution, still other answers are valid but **you dont need to use any dependency**:

First you have to create a new migration:

```
php artisan make:migration change_appointment_time_column_type
```

Then in that migration file `up()`, try:

```
    Schema::table('appointments', function ($table) {
        $table->string('time')->change();
    });
```

If you donot change the size default will be `varchar(191)` but If you want to change size of the field:

```
    Schema::table('appointments', function ($table) {
        $table->string('time', 40)->change();
    });
```

Then migrate the file by:

```
php artisan migrate
```

[more info from doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations#modifying-columns).

Comment: Don't you still need to use "doctrine/dbal" dependency?

Comment: This, in my opinion, is the only correct answer. Due to the facth that migration files are besides their main purpose to change the schema are the means of documenting and versioning for the DB schema changes, the separate migration file is a must here.

Comment: You still need `doctrine/dbal`.

Comment: The doctrine/dbal package is required.

Answer (score 10):

all other answers are Correct **But**  Before you run

```
php artisan migrate
```

**make sure you run this code first**

```
composer require doctrine/dbal
```

to avoid this error

> RuntimeException  : Changing columns for table "items" requires Doctrine DBAL; install
>   "doctrine/dbal".

Answer (score 8):

First composer requires `doctrine/dbal`, then:

```
$table->longText('column_name')->change();
```

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, but just a note about `->change()`:

> Only the following column types can be "changed": bigInteger, binary, boolean, date, dateTime, dateTimeTz, decimal, integer, json, longText, mediumText, smallInteger, string, text, time, unsignedBigInteger, unsignedInteger and unsignedSmallInteger.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#modifying-columns

If your column isn't one of these you will need to either drop the column or use the alter statement as mentioned in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was just replace *unsigned* with *index*

This is the full code:

```
    Schema::create('champions_overview',function (Blueprint $table){
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('cid')->index();
        $table->longText('name');
    });


    Schema::create('champions_stats',function (Blueprint $table){
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('championd_id')->index();
        $table->foreign('championd_id', 'ch_id')->references('cid')->on('champions_overview');
    });
```