# How do I update the column attribute of created_at in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I want to add a precision of my User's *created_at* column. So I created another migration file to update the attribute of *created_at* but it doesn't work.

Here's my migration file

```
 /**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dateTime('created_at', 3)->change();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropColumn('created_at');
    });
}
```

There's no error when I run the **php artisan migrate**. But whenever I try to create a new User it doesn't reflect changes.

I also added the date format in my User model

```
protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s.v';
```

Comment: Well, the created_at field is actually a timestamp field, not a dateTime, so maybe you are experiencing a doctrine limitation for changing column type. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32940495/laravel-migration-table-fields-type-change/40047800

Answer (score 0):

In the User model, add the `'created_at'` column to the `$fillable` property on the model.

```
protected $fillable = ['name', 'created_at'];
```

When you save/update the user, Laravel will automatically update the `'created_at'` field. Also, the correct date format for timestamp columns is `'Y-m-d H:i:s'`.