# How in migration to change type of field?

Tags: laravel

In Laravel 5.7 I created tiny field with rule

```
$table->tinyInteger('renewal_raise_invoice_before')->unsigned()->nullable()->after('renewal_raise_invoice_pre_pay');
```

But it appears that I need a bigger range.
Which is the correct way to change its type to smallInteger?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32940664/712558

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you ran into some mysql issues as I ran before with 5.7 & 5.8 and MySql 8 you can do RAW queries in the migration

```
Schema::table('table_name',function (Blueprint $table){

  DB::statement('ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY COLUMN renewal_raise_invoice_before smallint UNSIGNED NULL');

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make new migration with:

```
Schema::table('sometable',function (Blueprint $table){
        $table->smallInteger('renewal_raise_invoice_before')->unsigned()->nullable()->change();
    });
```